# Java - AVL tree search

Tags: java, tree

I have verified that the tree in question, `t`, is in fact an AVL tree. My problem is that, no matter if the searched string is in the tree or not, both `s` and `s2` are always `null`. I suspect this is more of a recursion issue than it is an AVL tree issue.

`t.val` yields the value of the string of the node. `t.left` and `t.right` yield the left and right children of the node, respectively.

```
   private static AVLTreeNode<String> search( AVLTreeNode<String> t, String x )
    {
        if( t==null ) return null;
        if( t.val==x ) return t;
        AVLTreeNode s=search(t.right,x);
        AVLTreeNode s2=search(t.left,x);
        if( s!=null ) return s;
        return s2;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `t.val.equals(x)` instead of `==` and everything should work fine. `==`checks if they both have the same reference (exactly the same string, saved in the same place in piece of memory) and `equals(Object)` checks if the content of both objects is equal (depending on implementation).

Comment: Oh, shoot! I always forget that. So sorry.